# extends de templates a partir do projeto para os apps

Tags: python, django

Tenho um projeto criados a partir do comando startproject ... onde na estrutura do mesmo, criei uma pasta templates, no qual, eu desejo ter templates htmls bases, ou seja, estendendo-os para as templates dos meus apps. É possível? se sim como eu posso fazer? Li aqui em alguma postagem, que eu deveria fazer isto a partir de um app mestre e não do projeto, é isto mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

Acabei por descobrir depois de muito ler diversos artigos sobre o assunto. Assim: para um extends a partir do projeto, basta incluir no settings.py na configuração TEMPLATE a seguinte configuração 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'site/templates')]... onde "site" é o seu projeto. Logo em seguida, crie uma pasta de nome "templates" na estrutura de seu projeto e uma nova pasta com o nome do se app, por exemplo "blog", ficando assim: "templates\blog". Feito, agora eu posso ter um base.html e usado em meus apps utilizando {% extends "blog/layout.html" %}.

Para mais detalhes, esta fonte me ajudou muito:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/howto/overriding-templates/